# Build competed with 4 failures

Tags: android, android-studio

> Android Studio Version : Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

[image]

This is the first time I want to run a Java application in Android Studio and I get these errors:

**FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.**

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.1.0/collection-1.1.0.jar
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.1.0/core-common-2.1.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.1.0/collection-1.1.0.jar
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.1.0/core-common-2.1.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.1.0/collection-1.1.0.jar
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not find core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.1.0/core-common-2.1.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Could not find collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.1.0/collection-1.1.0.jar
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Could not find core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.1.0/core-common-2.1.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 0s
23 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 11 up-to-date

Comment: See your build.gradle file in both app level and project level.